# Recursively ignore within a structured repo using .tfignore

Tags: tfs, tfignore

I have a solution with multiple projects. Each project uses a given Nuget that installs resources in some folders thar are shared with custom files. Something like

```
Solution
  ProjA
    Resources
      Text <from nuget>
      Img
    Text
  ProjB
    Resources
      Text <from nuget>
      Img
    Text
```

I already tried adding .tfignore at the solution level with
`Resources/Text`
But it doesn't work. The only way I succeeded was to copy the .tfignore into each project folder. Is there any better way?

Comment: Maybe try `*/Resources/Text`

Comment: Didn't work. Also, though I didn't mention it in my question, I realised that in some project, the folder could be deeper which wouldn't be covered if it worked. But thanks for the proposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.tfignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) file will ignore the given pattern in *all* subdirectories .  And it will ignore files *or* folders with the given name.  For folders, it will apply recursively.

As a result, a `.tfignore` with:

```
Text
```

This will ignore any folder named `Text` in your filesystem hierarchy, and it will ignore them recursively.

For those Text folder which is not under  `Resources/Tables`  you can **create .tfignore files in sub-folders to override the effects of a .tfignore file in a parent folder.**

***Note:***

1. A filespec is recursive unless prefixed by the `\` character.
2. This `.tfignore` file will not affect with those files already in source control. You need to remove them from source control first. Also make sure your .tfignore files have checked in source control.

Comment: Though this would work, I was hoping for a single file solution. I'll wait a little to see if anyth0ing else comes up and if not, will mark this as the answer. Remind me if I forget ;